# Unable to find element on new tab link

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

When I run a browser with extension a pop up arise that says "Disable developer mode" to do so my script clicks on Disable, it opens a new tab with url "chrome://extensions/"

Now to click on checkbox of developer mode it always give an error "Unable to locate element."

```
driver.findelement(By.id("toggle-dev-on"));
```

http://prntscr.com/f8fbde

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with "Disable developer mode" in `Settings` page? What are your exact test steps?

Comment: I want to uncheck developer checkbox so that this warning does not remain

Comment: Instead of performing "uncheck developer checkbox", how about getting rid of this to appear on your screen forever?

Comment: That would be great but I don't know how to do that through program

Comment: Check my Answer & update me. Thanks

Comment: Alright let me do that and I will update you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution for your Question:

As per best practices to work with Selenium 3.4.0 you must download the latest chromedriver v2.29 from [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/), update your Google Chrome to 58.x.

Updating your  chromedriver to v2.29 will solve your issue of `Disable developer mode`

To work with Google Chrome you can take help of `ChromeOptions` Class as follows:

```
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("start-maximized");
    options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
    options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.get("https://gmail.com");
```

Let me know if this solves your Question.

Comment: I'm glad to be able to help you out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the appropriate browser profile to have JS disabled. Like for FireFox/Chrome you can tell Selenium which profile to use.

**Chrome :**

```
Map prefs = new HashMap();
prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications", 2);
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

**FireFox :**

```
FirefoxProfile ffprofile = new FirefoxProfile();
ffprofile.setPreference("dom.webnotifications.enabled", false);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffprofile);
```

Hope this will work out for your case.

Comment: Still facing the same issue :(

Comment: `ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("chrome.switches","--disable-extensions");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "//src//test//resources//chromedriver_new.exe"));
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);`

Use this alternative while creating chrome driver